# How to connect to Docker replica set with node.js mongodb 4+ driver where MongoDB is set up with Docker hostnames?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, connection, replicaset

I successfully set up MongoDB replica set with docker-compose using Docker hostnames `db1`, `db2`, `db3`. However, these hostnames are of course not available outside of Docker unless I edit e.g. `/etc/hosts`.

The MongoDB servers use port 27017 inside the container but are exposed on ports 27017, 27027, 27037, respectively, and MongoDB servers are started with `--bind_ip_all` (I also tried `--bind_ip localhost,db1,127.0.0.1` etc.).

Now I want to connect a non-Docker node.js application to MongoDB.

Connecting to my local replica set in Docker worked with the node.js mongodb@^3.7.3 driver but now fails with mongodb@^4, including 4.0.0.

I'm using this snippet adapted from the [MongoDB driver documentation page](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/connection/), adding only the `useUnifiedTopology` flag to be able to connect:

```js
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

// Connection URI
const uri = "mongodb://user:pass@localhost/db";
// Create a new MongoClient
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true });

async function run() {
    try {
        // Connect the client to the server
        await client.connect();
        // Establish and verify connection
        await client.db("admin").command({ ping: 1 });
        console.log("Connected successfully to server");
    } finally {
        // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
        await client.close();
    }
}

run().catch(console.dir);
```

`useUnifiedTopology` seems to have disappeared with mongodb driver version 4.

I tried different single server connection strings such as only with `localhost` as in the example (i.e. connecting to the primary only), `127.0.0.1`, with and without port spec `:27017` as well as replica set connection strings with `localhost:27017,localhost:27027,localhost:27037` and appended `?replicaSet=rs0` and/or specified `replicaSet: "rs0"`, `readPreference: "primary"` (or `"nearest"` etc.) in the connection options but all fail like this:

```js
MongoServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db1
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/dev/x/m/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:310:38)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'db1:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'db2:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'db3:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'rs0',
    maxSetVersion: 2,
    maxElectionId: ObjectId { [Symbol(id)]: [Buffer [Uint8Array]] },
    commonWireVersion: 9,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  }
}
```

**How can I connect to a Dockerized MongoDB replica set that is using Docker-internal hostnames?**

Do I really need "public" hostnames that are valid both inside and outside of Docker for this to work?

Looking at the question [Connect to MongoDB Replica Set running inside Docker with Java (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47998855/connect-to-mongodb-replica-set-running-inside-docker-with-java-windows), this seems to be an unsupported case, however, it was **working** with the old mongodb 3 driver.

From that question:

> In conclusion, to support key features of replica sets, we require that the hostnames used in a replica set config are reachable from the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems specifying `directConnection: true` in the connection options makes it work, preventing server delegation / redirection:

```js
// Connection URI
const uri = "mongodb://user:pass@localhost/db";
// Create a new MongoClient
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { directConnection: true });
```

Comment: I was trying to connect to a mongo replica set  running 5.x inside a docker container  from nodejs app running in another container. I was using Mongo driver 4.x. at client app.  The replica set was a single node replica set. directConnection option was necessary to connect to the server.